# Upload remote file via Slack API

Tags: node.js, axios, slack-api

I'm trying to upload a remote file via Slack API `https://slack.com/api/files.upload` using Node with `axios` library.
https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

```
async filesUpload(token, channel, content, filename) {
    const form = new FormData()
    form.append('token', token)
    form.append('channels', channel)
    form.append('content', content)
    form.append('filename', filename)
    form.append('filetype', 'auto')

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
      form,
      {
        headers: form.getHeaders(),
      }
    )
}
// url is a publicly available remote jpg image 
const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
  responseType: 'blob',
})

filesUpload('XXXX', 'XXXXX', data, 'foo.jpg')
```

Slack API says all good, and post its content (some gibberish) to the channel and in the response I get plain text filetype:

```
...
mimetype: 'text/plain',
filetype: 'text',
...
```

I'm pretty sure is about encoding I'm sending, but I'm out of options. I was trying to downloading the file with `responseType: 'blob'`, `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` but no luck.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to fix it using axios, but I switched the request to https://github.com/request/request-promise and everything works fine.